# Inconsistent jQuery function when resizing elements on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ahoy!
I've built a little script to check the size of the left-hand margin on page load, resize a div there to fill it, and change the header div to float next to it.

Here's the code:

```
function buildHeader() {
            var containerMarginLeft = $(".container_16:not(:first)").css("margin-left");
            var headerHeight = $("#header").height();
            $("#stripe").width(containerMarginLeft).height(headerHeight).css("float", "left");
            $(".container_16:first").css("float", "left");
            $("#header").css("margin-left", 0).width(950);
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){   
            // Manipulate layout for the first time
            buildHeader();
            // Manipulate layout when window is resized
            var resizeTimer = null;
            $(window).bind('resize', function() {
                if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
                      resizeTimer = setTimeout(buildHeader, 100);
                   });
        });
```

And the demonstration is here: http://robertmay.me.uk/mockups/plane.html (it creates the line that stretches on the left).
Now, it works in webkit browsers. It doesn't work in Mozilla, and I've not even tried it in IE.
Anyone have any ideas as to why it doesn't seem to work in Mozilla? I have a feeling it might have something to do with the CSS.

Comment: In Firefox 3.0 the line is a little too short compared to the results in Safari 4.0 where the line goes all the way to the right. So what is your question specifically? Are you looking for a workaround? or just verification of the behavior you mention? You could try a mix of an image floated right and a background image and pray that they line up...

Comment: Ah ha, so it works in Firefox 3 on Windows? It doesn't on the Mac version. I've seen what you're describing and it's not a huge problem, it's about 50px too short for whatever reason. Any idea why? On the Mac FF3, the line div isn't even there, the header just floats to the left.

Comment: I've had a look using Firebug, and in FF3 for Mac it isn't giving the stripe div a proper width, it's set to 0px. Any ideas?

Comment: the stripe feature works fine in IE, the rest of the the page is a little messed up but that's what I expect in IE (ps running IE through a plugin for FF).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".container_16:not(:first)").css("margin-left");
```

This line gives a result of '0px' in Firefox regardless of how wide the window gets. However, Firebug Lite in Safari shows this value as changing depending on the width of the window.

The problem seems to be with the .css('margin-left') part of the statement, since $(".container_16:not(:first)") returns the same element in both browsers. Indeed, Firebug in Firefox shows the Computed Style for this element as having '0px' for marginLeft and marginRight, but this is non-zero in Safari.

As expected, changing from 'margin-left' to 'marginLeft' makes no difference, nor does accessing the attribute directly, like $(".container_16:not(:first)")[0].style.marginLeft, because Firefox is computing it wrong in the first place.

Sorry I don't have an answer, but hopefully this will lead you in the right direction. For me though I would try to align the layout using just CSS, resorting to JavaScript fixes only as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for narrowing it down for me! I have tried using just CSS as a solution, but I had a very narrow window to get it working and getting the same effect in CSS seems much trickier. I just tested the site in FF3 for Windows and it worked more or less fine, so it seems to be a problem solely with FF for Mac. Very odd!